# I can't convert string data when reading from marshaled c library

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

Hi I am having problem when I read data from my national ID using external .dll which is provided by government. DLL is written in C. I have wrapper for it written in C#. It loads all data except my name and surname which is different than other data. All other fields are Latin characters but my name and surname are in Cyrillic.

This is my code in wrapper class

```
[DllImport(DLL, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = 
StaticData.READ_FIXED_DATA)]
public static extern int EidReadFixedPersonalData(ref PEID_FIXED_PERSONAL_DATA d);
```

PEID_FIXED_PERSONAL_DATA class

```
public struct PEID_FIXED_PERSONAL_DATA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
    public string personalNumber;

    int personalNumberSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
    public string surname;

    int surnameSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
    string givenName;

    int givenNameSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
    string parentGivenName;

    int parentGivenNameSize;

    ...
}
```

Fields I am having issue with are surname and givenName
[image: These are values that i get]

Things I have tried to do

1. Tried changing CharSet on DLLImport
2. Tried changing UnmanagedType to all possible string types in
   combination with CharSet Unicode/ANSI
3. Tried using Encoding to extract byte[] and convert to some other
   encoding, also with type and CharSet changes along

Nothing seems to work.
Can anyone help me to find out what the problem is?

If it helps I have C class which is reference for creating wrapper.
in struct tagEID_FIXED_PERSONAL_DATA it says

```
char surname[200];
```

Comment: "The character type used with ByValTStr is determined by the CharSet argument of the StructLayoutAttribute attribute applied to the containing structure" I don't see that anywhere, and I would imagine you need `ANSI`

Comment: Are you sure the Visual Studio debugger is capable of displaying Cyrillic letters? It could be the case that the data has actually been fetched correctly, since I am unable to identify any mistakes in the interop process. Have you tried extracting the string to a text document with the appropiate encoding or viewing the raw data to see whether it actually contains what you need?